# Multi-input Keras model resulting in low accuracy (is my model setup incorrect?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

This is my first time creating a multi-input keras model, and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong as my training accuracy is not rising above 50 percent.  If I use a single-input model, I can get to 90 percent plus pretty easily. This model uses the **same input but different sizes of the input** and then takes the max of the softmax prediction as the final prediction. So, I would assume it would be easier to train the model.

Here is the code:

```
def full_model_2(model_key):
    base_model, preprocess = basemodel(model_key)  #base model is just an imported imagenet model
    base_model2, preprocess = basemodel(model_key)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.name = layer.name + "dup"

#first model    
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x =  Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
predictions_x = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(x)

#second model
y = base_model2.output
y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(y)
y = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y =  Dense(512, activation='relu')(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
predictions_y = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(y)
#predictions = Average()([predictions_x, predictions_y])
predictions = Maximum()([predictions_x, predictions_y])
model = Model(inputs= [base_model.input,base_model2.input], outputs=predictions)
for layer in model.layers[:-10]:
    layer.trainable = False
return model, preprocess
```

My generator looks something like this (take two generators and creates two inputs)

```
def train_generator():
    train_gen, _ = create_generators(batch_size, preprocess, img_size)
    train_gen2, _ = create_generators(batch_size, preprocess, img_size2)
    print(train_gen.seed)
    print(train_gen2.seed)
    while True:
        X1i = train_gen.next()
        X2i = train_gen2.next()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X1i[1]
```

Here is the original generator function:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = preprocess)
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = seed,
    target_size = (img_size, img_size),
    batch_size = batch_size, 
    class_mode = 'categorical')

return train_generator


 model.compile(optimizer= r_optimizer,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I have plotted the inputs from the generators, and I am indeed getting the same images but different sizes, so the input from generators seems to be okay.

I am thinking my model setup is off.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Setting all layers to untrainable up until the last 10 layers might be the issue. What are you trying to do with that part of the code? Which layers do you want to be trainable/untrainable? In addition, taking the maximum is a little strange since your output will not be a probability distribution anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The last 10 layers, were my attempt to only train the added layers (layers added to the base models). I did play around with the number, and eventually for fine tuning went up to 30 layers or so.

As for your second point, do you think I would need to adjust my loss function?
My attempt with the usage of Max was to grab the probability of the more sure model, hoping it would increase my accuracy. 

So if model 1 thinks the image is A, but model 2 think the image is B with a higher probability, It would choose the softmax value of model 2.

Comment: So instead of modifying `model`'s layers, I would suggest iterating over the `base_model`'s layers and making them untrainable. The problem with editing the `model`'s layers is that each of the layers you added are considered layers, and the `base_model`s themselves are also considered layers, so you may be making things untrainable or trainable that you don't want to. As for the loss, that should be fine. You could add an extra concatenate and dense layer with softmax activation, though, to make sure it's a probability distribution.

Comment: Also, do you get a good accuracy just from using one of the ImageNet models and making it trainable? You mention a 90% accuracy, so I just want to know where that came from.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try making the `base_model` untrainable. As for you `concat` suggestion. Are you suggesting I use `concat` instead of maximum? I wonder if adding a dense layer *after* the maximum layer, and using softmax on the dense layer would be okay. I will try both and see what happens. Thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: The 90% is not from this specific model makeup, but from when I had trained each of the models seperately.